Book where the main character was called the white wraith and had golden blood
From what I can remember, the main character in this series was a girl and, in this world, there existed humans and a dragon-like species. Think Dragonborn from Dungeons & Dragons. These dragon-like people have spectacular abilities and live in a city in the sky, if I remember correctly. People can obtain similar powers by replacing parts of themselves, such as their limbs or eyes, with dragon parts. The procedure makes your blood turn black. This is where the main character stands out, as I believe they had a mechanical heart or some kind of implant that made it so, even though they had dragon parts, their blood was gold like the dragons, making them much stronger. I think they made the device themselves and a lot of people were after it. It may have been called Pandora's Box or something similar, but I can't be sure.
I remember really enjoying this book, but after I read the first in a library (around 8 or 9 years ago, give or take a year), I couldn't find the sequel and eventually completely forgot the title.

In roughly which year did you read this?

@LogicDictates I think ot was around 8 or 9 years ago give or take a year. It was a very long time ago but I'm fairly certain about what I've written down here. Also please excuse the typos I typed all of this on my phone lol.

I tried to clean up the typos. If I got anything wrong, don't hesitate to edit the question yourself to fix it.

Much obliged it looks much cleaner.

Is this The Alchemists of Loom (2017) by Elise Kova...? It's the first book in the Loom Saga trilogy.

Ari lost everything she once loved when the Five Guilds’ resistance fell to the Dragon King. Now, she uses her unparalleled gift for clockwork machinery in tandem with notoriously unscrupulous morals to contribute to a thriving underground organ market. There isn’t a place on Loom that is secure from the engineer turned thief, and her magical talents are sold to the highest bidder as long as the job defies their Dragon oppressors.
Cvareh would do anything to see his sister usurp the Dragon King and sit on the throne. His family’s house has endured the shame of being the lowest rung in the Dragons’ society for far too long. The Alchemist Guild, down on Loom, may just hold the key to putting his kin in power, if Cvareh can get to them before the Dragon King’s assassins.
When Ari stumbles upon a wounded Cvareh, she sees an opportunity to slaughter an enemy and make a profit off his corpse. But the Dragon sees an opportunity to navigate Loom with the best person to get him where he wants to go.
He offers her the one thing Ari can’t refuse: A wish of her greatest desire, if she brings him to the Alchemists of Loom.



My word I think you've found it. I've been searching for this series so long it isn't even funny thank you so much.
